# How do I insert data from a Python dictionary to MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I manipulated some data from MySQL and the resulting dictionary "data" (print data) displays something like this :

```
{'1': ['1', 'K', abc, 'xyz', None, None, None, datetime.date(2009, 6, 18)],
 '2': ['2', 'K', efg, 'xyz', None, None, None, None],
 '3': ['3', 'K', ijk, 'xyz', None, None, None, datetime.date(2010, 2, 5, 16, 31, 2)]}
```

How do I create a table and insert these values in a MySQL table? In other words, how do I dump them to MySQL or CSV? Not sure how to deal with datetime.date and None values. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you missing one `None`? (use a class...)

Comment: Yep, updated! THanks. This is just sample data. Thanks Ken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some basic code to create a MySQL database, and insert some data.

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

THEHOST="localhost"
THEUSER="user"
THEPASSWD="passwd"
THEDB="database"

connection=MySQLdb.connect(
    host=THEHOST,user=THEUSER,passwd=THEPASSWD,db=THEDB)
cursor=connection.cursor()

abc,efg,ijk=1,2,3

data={'1': ['1', 'K', abc, 'xyz', None, None, None, datetime.date(2009, 6, 18)],
      '2': ['2', 'K', efg, 'xyz', None, None, None, None],
      '3': ['3', 'K', ijk, 'xyz', None, None, None,
            datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 5, 16, 31, 2)]}

sql='''\
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp (id int auto_increment primary key,
    field1 varchar(8),
    field2 int,
    field3 varchar(8),
    field4 bool,
    field5 varchar(8),
    field6 varchar(8),
    field7 datetime )'''

cursor.execute(sql)

sql='''\
INSERT INTO temp (id, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
'''
cursor.executemany(sql, data.values())
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

I keep getting this error though : TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting.

I used this : 

sql='''\
INSERT INTO delUseThisTable (`key`, `primary`)
VALUES (%s, %s)
'''
cursor.executemany(sql, data.values())

I have 78 columns in this table. I tried with 2 columns for a start and it fails. Ideas? Thank u!

Comment: @NJTechie: Perhaps try `print data.values()`. It should be a list of 2-element lists, such as `[[1,'K'],[2,'L']]`. The inner lists must have exactly 2 elements. Otherwise, you may get the error `TypeError: not all arguments converted...`

Comment: OMG, sir you are a genius :) I didn't know we have to insert all of them at once rather than just 2 columns! Definitely learnt a thing or 2! Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.date` matches `DATE` fields, and `None` becomes `NULL`. Use [`.executemany()`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) in conjunction with [`dict.values()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) in order to perform the INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

Most dbapi-compliant connectors to MySQL will automatically convert Python's `None` to SQL's `NULL` and Python's `datetime` objects to SQL `TIMESTAMP`s.

Really, you just need to open a connection to your database, get a cursor, and iterate over the dictionary doing the insert.  Without knowing your schema, it's impossible to give you sample code, though.